# install ingest-attachment plugin error

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I downloaded ingest-attachment plugin 6.3.0 version to my machine and trying to install using command prompt in my windows machine and am getting the error.

Please find the error that am getting while installing ingest-attachment plugin.

I have install elasticsearch 6.2.3 version.

```
D:\1SearchEngine\elasticsearch-6.2.3\elasticsearch-6.2.3>bin\elasticsearch-plugi
n install d:\1SearchEngine\ingest-attachment\ingest-attachment-6.3.0.zip
-> Downloading d:\1SearchEngine\ingest-attachment\ingest-attachment-6.3.0.zip
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: d
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:600)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.downloadZip(InstallPlu
ginCommand.java:329)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.download(InstallPlugin
Command.java:253)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.execute(InstallPluginC
ommand.java:221)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.execute(InstallPluginC
ommand.java:212)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwar
eCommand.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:1
24)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.MultiCommand.execute(MultiCommand.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:1
24)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginCli.main(PluginCli.java:48)

D:\1SearchEngine\elasticsearch-6.2.3\elasticsearch-6.2.3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugin-management-custom-url.html) says that:

```
bin\elasticsearch-plugin install file:///C:/path/to/plugin.zip
```

You are missing `file://`.

Comment: yes its worked for me with `file:///` , but now am getting different error `ERROR: elasticsearch directory is missing in the plugin zip`

Comment: You can not instal a 6.3.0 plugin on a 6.2.3 version. Fix one or the other.